# Setting a hyperlink text color in axlsx

Tags: ruby, colors, hyperlink, axlsx

I'm trying to set the foreground color of text in a hyperlink cell but it doesn't seem to work.

Using something like: `sheet["A1"].color = "0000FF"` works fine for a normal cell, but not for a hyperlinked cell

This code simply creates a link to cell D1 on the "Log" sheet (which works fine) but A1 never turns blue!

`sheet.add_hyperlink :location => "'Log'!D1", :target => :sheet, :ref => "A1"`
  `sheet["A1"].color = "0000FF"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There are two important things to do before applying a color to a link:

1. You have to define the color within a style, and
2. You have to know the exact address of the cell in question.

Styles are normally applied to rows, but in this case you want to apply it to a specific cell.  This is possible, but you need to address the cell directly *through* the Sheet Object.  Also, and somewhat counter intuitively, the 'add_hyperlink' method is available to the Sheet object, not the Cell.  So beware of that as well.

Here is an example of how to apply a style to a cell containing a link:

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new
p.workbook do |wb|
  wb.styles do |s|
    blue_link = s.add_style :fg_color => '0000FF'
    wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Anchor Link Test") do |sheet|
      sheet.add_row ['Title', 'Link']

      # Define the row here, we will use that later
      row = sheet.add_row ['Google', 'Click to go']

      # Add the hyperlink by addressing the column you have used and add 1 to the row's index value.
      sheet.add_hyperlink :location => "http://www.google.com", :ref => "B#{row.index + 1}"
      sheet["B#{row.index + 1}"].style = blue_link
    end
    s = p.to_stream()
    File.open("anchor_link_test.xlsx", 'w') { |f| f.write(s.read) }
  end
end
```

Final note:  You might note that I have written this spreadsheet using the methods

```
s = p.to_stream()
File.open("anchor_link_test.xlsx", 'w') { |f| f.write(s.read) }
```

There is evidence presented [on the Axlsx Github Issues Page](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/61)  which shows that this means of writing out the file is significantly faster than

```
p.serialize
```

Just thought that deserved mention somewhere on StackOverflow!

Comment: Awesome answer! You might also consider setting the style in the add_row call via the :style option.  http://rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Worksheet:add_row

Comment: I recently learned about assigning styles as you described and have used it effectively as well.  I may revise the above answer when I have the chance to offer that alternative.

Comment: One can also declare styles just by calling `blue_link = wb.styles.add_style ...`.  This is handy if you have a large document and don't want to use a `wb.styles do .. end` block.

Comment: For those reading later: `row.cells[123].color = "0000FF"` seems to work for me too!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
require 'axlsx'
p = Axlsx::Package.new
ws = p.workbook.add_worksheet
ws.add_row ['hoge-hoge']
ws['A1'].color = '0000FF'
ws.add_hyperlink :location => 'F6', :target => :sheet, :ref => 'A1'
p.serialize 'where_is_my_color.xlsx'
```

Can you post a larger example of your code that does not set the color?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Axlsx is only applying custom styles to String data types.  Fixed this by setting each column to type :string like this:

`Sheet.add_row [ "1", "2", "3" ], :types => [:string, :string, :string]`

Thanks Randy!